# UITextView Height Adjustment

Tags: swift, uikit, uitextview

I'm trying to create a ViewController which will hold some large text. I used `UILabel` but since the text can be long, it won't work. Trying to switch to `UITextView`but I'm having some problems.

I'm using `ScrollView` since there is a image on the top and button on the bottom. So I don't it scrolling inside the `UITextView` itself. I've disabled it.

I want to Text to height itself automatically according to the text length. So it can scroll with the images, buttons etc. Just like the apps Instapaper, Medium, Pocket etc.

I've tried all the code and solutions on StackOverflow, but they either didn't work or they were Objective-C.

**Storyboard Structure:**
View Controller -> View -> ScrollView -> Image, TextView, Button

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
  var theContent = fromClass.text

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textView.text = theContent
  }
}
```

Comment: U need to add a view inside scroll view as a container for Image, TextView and button. New added view has to have equal width, height for super view of scroll view.

Comment: @yerpy  , OK I've done that but how can I make the TextView adjust height, according to the content?

Comment: You need to track the size of the string and depending of it, resizing text view height.

Answer (score 0):

There is few ways to change the size of the `UITextView`

```
extension String {

    func bounds(approximated width: CGFloat, approximated height: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGRect {
        let size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        let attribs = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font]

        return NSString(string: self).boundingRect(with: size, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attribs, context: nil)
    }
}
```

`approximated width` = width of your `UITextView` I assume it is going to be static value which you won't change.

`approximated height` = minimal height of your `UITextView`.

The method going to return frame of your text input. Take from it height property and depending of how big is that change the size of the `UITextView`.

If it won't satisfy you, you can use another way.

```
func heightOfString(_ attributes: [NSAttributedKeyString : Any]) -> CGFloat {
    let size = self.size(withAttributes: attributes)
    return size.height
}
```

The same usage as from above.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your view hierarchy to the following view hierarchy :

View Controller -> View -> ScrollView -> View1 -> Image, UILabel, Button

1- give view1 top-left-bottom-right constraints and and align it center X to it's parent view

2- add `UIImageView` in the top of View1 and give it top-left-right constraint and a fixed height constraint.

3- add a `UILabel` and give it top constraint to the image and right-bottom-left constraint to it's superview.

make `UILabel` number of lines = 0

The content not should be scrollable.

**Note that:** in your case; you do not need `UITextView` .

If you want to use `UITextView`:

1- add a height constraint to the `UITextView` and connect an outlet to it 
called: constTextViewHeight

```
let textViewContentHeight = textView.contentSize.height//call this line after adding the text to the textView
self.constTextViewHeight.contant = textViewContentHeight
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

[image]